# OpenGl verex2f but pixels are integers

Tags: opengl, pixel

when im using this code:

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f(2.5, 2.5);
    glVertex2f(3.2, 3.2);
glEnd();
```

if im understand correctly, so the coordinates are relative to bottom left corner of the screen, but what are those coordinates?

if they are in pixels unit aren't they suppose to be integers?

what is the meaning of using floating points when pixels are integer units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if they are in pixels unit aren't they suppose to be integers?

They aren't in pixel units. The vertex data is *transformed* to the final window space (=pixel) coordinates throughout the pipeline. These input coordinates you specify are in *object space*, and this is a coordinate system which you are defining as you see fit.

You should really make yourself familiar with the [coordinate transformations](https://open.gl/transformations).

Also, you should be aware that in OpenGL, you are not drawing *pixels*. You are drawing *graphics primitives* - points, lines, triangles - which are defined by a certain number of vertices each.

> what is the meaning of using floating points when pixels are integer units?

Even in window space, floating-point coordinates are useful. Pixels are not discrete points, but represent some area. OpenGL (and other render APIs) define a pixel in window space to be a square with side lenght of 1 unit. Vertices can fall to any (sub-pixel) position inside such a pixel square, and rasterization rules will be applied to generate the appropriate pixel-sized fragments for the primitives you are rendering.